# Change the font-size and color of the labels on the axes/ticks in D3 Observable (no text appended)

Tags: d3.js, observablehq

I am using [this](https://observablehq.com/d/542bcce9ea0b40a3@195) Bar Chart on **D3 Observable**. I need to change the font-size and color of the labels on the axes/ticks. In the previous D3 approach you could simply do this in CSS like:

```
text {
    fill : white;
    font-size : 22px;
}
```

But Observable doesn't provide the usual HTML file for placing **CSS**.

If you look at the file there doesn't appear to be any **text appended**, although in inspect element you can see the labels are indeed "text"

I tried adding style to the appended g:

```
svg.append("g")
  .style("fill", "white")
  .call(xAxis);
```

But to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an [Observable](https://observablehq.com) notebook you can add your CSS using the `html` method with a template literal, like this:

```
html`<style>
  text {
    fill : white;
    font-size : 22px;
}
  </style>`
```

Just create a new cell (clicking the `+` sign) and copy/paste the snippet above.

Comment: @Cybernetic What link? Regarding the code, click the `+` symbol on the top, create a new cell, and copy/paste the snippet. Then, a blue arrow will show up on the right hand side: click it to run the cell.

Comment: I see. I found out how to do it using style and attr as usual, but your answer also works. Gave you the win. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can style the text on this chart in Observable by looking for the cells containing the **XAxis** and **yAxis**.

[image]

and...

[image]

Below the .attr("transform") lines add this line for font size:

```
.style("font-size", "22px")
```

...and this line for color:

```
.attr("color", "red")
```

Not sure why D3 decided to change .style("fill" to .attr("color"

Your cells should now look like this:

```
xAxis = g => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
    .style("font-size", "22px")
    .attr("color", "red")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
        .tickSizeOuter(0))
```

and...

```
yAxis = g => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
    .style("font-size", "22px")
    .attr("color", "red")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
```

**Result**:

[image]